# What are some examples of total derived functors that can't be computed from a functorial replacement?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homotopy-theory

(Or more generally, what are some examples of Kan extensions which are not pointwise?)

By a total derived functor of a functor $F: C \to D$, I simply mean a (left or right) Kan extension of $F$ along some localization $C \to C[W^{-1}]$ at a class of arrows $W$. Usually when such a Kan extension exists, it comes from a functor $L: C \to C$ and a natural transformation $\eta: 1_C \implies L$ (or the other way around depending on handedness) such that on the image of $L$, $F$ already takes arrows in $W$ to isomorphisms, and the components of $\eta$ are in $W$ (Riehl calls this a *deformation* of the functor $F$, but I'm not sure how standard this terminology is). When such an $L$ exists, the total derived functor is simply $F \circ L$.

My question is: does a total derived functor ever exist without such a deformation / replacement functor $L$ existing? I presume the answer is yes, and I'd like to see some examples.

My motivation for this question actually comes from the fact that when a deformation exists, the Kan extension involved is pointwise, and in fact absolute (preserved by all functors). I'm actually just [trying to understand pointwiseness of Kan extensions better](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220246/what-is-the-point-of-pointwise-kan-extensions) by looking at examples of non-pointwise Kan extensions. There is an example of a non-pointwise Kan extension in Borceux's *Handbook of Categorical Algebra*, and it generalizes a bit, but I'd like to see more examples. Since the codomain category of a total derived functor rarely has many (co)limits, it's a good candidate to admit non-pointwise Kan extensions into it, and it seems one just has to get around the fact that these Kan extension *are* pointwise if they are computed as deformations.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In fact, one such example comes from homotopical algebra:

> **Proposition.** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small homotopical category and let $\gamma : \mathcal{C} \to \operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{C}$ be the localising functor. Then $\mathcal{C} (-, -) : \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$ admits a left Kan extension along $\gamma^\mathrm{op} \times \gamma : \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \times \mathcal{C} \to \operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \times \operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{C}$, namely $\operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{C} (-, -) : \operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \times \operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$.

Bizarrely enough, this is a *pointwise* left Kan extension – so the proof is a direct calculation. If $\gamma : \mathcal{C} \to \operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{C}$ has a (necessarily fully faithful) right adjoint, then this can also be calculated using a right deformation. I think the converse is also true, but at any rate, right deformations usually do not exist.

Comment: Mysterious pointwiseness strikes again! I was really hoping that this question would inevitably lead to non-pointwise extensions, but this is interesting too.

Comment: This computation comes down to showing that a morphism in $\mathrm{Ho}\mathcal{C}$ is the same thing as a triple of composable morphisms in $\mathrm{Ho}\mathcal{C}$ where the middle one has a lift to $\mathcal{C}$, modulo the equivalence relation generated by identifying two triples if the middle arrow of one factors through the middle arrow of the other in $\mathcal{C}$, compatibly with the other arrows. I think the hypotheses can be weakened to say that $\mathcal{C}$ is any category with a class of arrows such that $\mathrm{Ho}\mathcal{C}$ is still locally small, right?

Comment: Sure. This is only to ensure that the hom-functors land in $\mathbf{Set}$, of course.

Comment: And I guess this pointwiseness isn't really mysterious at all, since $\mathsf{Set}$ is cocomplete. Although this answer is interesting, I'm going to hold out for something _more_ interesting. I feel justified because (1) When people say "total derived functor" they usually mean something into some sort of homotopy category, not a cocomplete category like $\mathsf{Set}$ and (2) I was really interested in non-pointwise Kan extensions in the first place.