# Is this a characterization of cocompleteness?

Tags: ct.category-theory

If $A$ is a cocomplete category and $C$ is small, we can say that for all functor $C \stackrel{l}{\to} A$ there exists the Kan Extension Lan$_{y_C}(l): \hat{C} \to A$. Moreover, the Kan extension is pointwise.

Is it known if the other implication is true? Namely:

> Conj:  If for all functor $C \stackrel{l}{\to} A$ there exists the Kan Extension Lan$_{y_C}(l): \hat{C} \to A$ then $A$ is cocomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then answer is yes if you assume the extensions are pointwise.

Let $\ast$ be the terminal presheaf on $\hat C$. Because the extension is poinwise, we have $Lan_{y_C}(l)(\ast) = \varinjlim_{c \in C} l(c)$. This can be seen, for example, by calculating the colimit using the category of elements of $\ast$, which is just $C$ itself.

Comment: Since I am not assuming that A has colimits, how can I say that the extension is pointwise?

Comment: There are many ways to say that an extension is poinwise. One way is to say that the Kan extension is preserved by representable functors. But now I see I did not read carefully enough -- although you mention that the extension is pointwise in the cocomplete case, you didn't assume it in your question statement.

Comment: This is because I didn't know how to say that there  are pointwise without colimits. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Actually, it's natural to guess that the answer is _no_ if you don't assume pointwiseness. This might be a candidate example statement for [the point of pointwise Kan extensions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220246/what-is-the-point-of-pointwise-kan-extensions)...